# iOS location services in the background to occur at smaller intervals or distances

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, core-location

the following code is my app delegate file, that I updated for swift 3.0.2

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var significatLocationManager : CLLocationManager?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if(UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus == UIBackgroundRefreshStatus.available){
        print("yes")
    }else{
        print("no")
    }

    if launchOptions != nil{


        let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary

        if remoteNotif != nil {
            self.significatLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.significatLocationManager?.delegate = self
            self.significatLocationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                self.significatLocationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            }
            self.significatLocationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        }else{

            self.locationManager           = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                self.locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            }

            self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

    }else{

        self.locationManager           = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self
        self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }

        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    }

    return true
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    //let locationArray = locations as NSArray
    //let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    //let coord = locationObj.coordinate


    let currentLocation = locations.last!
    //print("Current location: \(currentLocation)")
    print("delegate longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    print("delegate latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")

    let t_longtitude = String(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let t_latitude = String(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let longtitude:Double = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude as Double
    let latitude:Double = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude as Double
    let svd_longtitude:Double = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "longtitude") as? Double)!
    let svd_latitude:Double = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latitude") as? Double)!
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longtitude)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocation(latitude: svd_latitude, longitude: svd_longtitude)
    let distanceInMeters = coordinate1.distance(from: coordinate2) // result is in meters
    print("distanceInMeters: \(distanceInMeters)")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(longtitude, forKey: "longtitude")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    let device_id = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
    let status = update_device(longtitude: t_longtitude, latitude: t_latitude, device_id: device_id)
    print("status: \(status)")
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if self.significatLocationManager != nil {

        self.significatLocationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }else{

        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }


}

func update_device(longtitude: String, latitude:String, device_id:String) -> Int {

    print("update device")

    let deviceID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
    var status:Int = 0

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://someurl")!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "device_id=\(deviceID)&longtitude=\(longtitude)&latitude=\(latitude)"

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString:String = (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))!
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

        let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString)

        //UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "myUserDetails")
        //UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        //let status:Int = dict?["status"] as! Int
        print("status: \(status)")
        status = dict?["status"] as! Int

    }

    task.resume()
    return status

}



func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
       return nil
   }


  }
```

I have asked for allow always, updated info.plist with

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to your location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to your location</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

The code works and my db is getting filled, but when app is in the background didUpdateLocations is triggered to far apart from location to location. What can I do to make app call didUpdateLocations when change between former location and new location is less then 200 meters

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set location for 100 meteres like this, it will update you if location is changed to 100 meteres from current location

```
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
```

Comment: When you are intializing CLLocationManager and setting your delegate where you use this code.